# Short story where the discovery of God makes the newspaper headlines

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story about the discovery of God by scientists that makes the newspaper headlines. The story ends a with headline like: God dead; is not able to alter anything. 80s perhaps?